# How hexadecimal representation is more compact and intelligible for documentation?

Tags: information-theory, number-theory, encoding-scheme

My textbook says,
                    "Instead, it is far better to use a hexadecimal representation for documentation purposes. Whether or not a code represents a binary number, it can be treated as such and converted to the corresponding hexadecimal number. This makes the representation more compact and, as a result, more intelligible."
                 would any body explain it to me plz? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is just the ordinary English language use of the word "compact": taking up less space. As to whether it's more intelligible, eh, that's basically a matter of reader preference and very context-dependent. Probably nobody wants to read "The system supports up to 0x64 users."

Comment: I agree $13_{97}\%$ with this answer.

Comment: Alright but what does that mean, " Whether or not a code represents a binary number, it can be treated as such and converted to the corresponding hexadecimal number"